# Ordinal Arithmetic $(\omega + 1)+\omega$

Tags: set-theory

Simplify:

- $(\omega + 1)+\omega$
- $\omega +\omega^2$
- $(\omega + 1)*\omega^2$

where $\omega = \mathbb{N}$

I was looking another examples like a post here with $\omega * (\omega+1)$ but there is no the commutative of ordinals

Comment: Have you tried applying the definitions of $+$ and $\cdot$?

Comment: The sum between two ordinal is evaluated with $\omega+\alpha $=sup${\omega+\theta, \theta < \alpha}$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$\omega+\omega$$
$$\omega^2$$

$$\omega^3 $$

Comment: Could you explain the second one, please? I am learning this topic on my own.

Comment: Its just like $1+\omega=\omega$. Here, $\omega^2$ is $\omega$ many $\omega$'s on top of each other. Adding one to the beginning doesnt change things.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you so much.